# MSSQL insert rows into relational tables.

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database

I have two tables. `Person` and `Phones`. Many phones numbers could be associated with one person by foreign key. If I want to add a phone number and map it to particular person, how my SQL should look like?

In my understanding:

1. SQL statement should be transact, therefore first I have to insert person into `Person` table and after insert phone number in `Phones` and map it with just inserted row in `Person` table.
2. What if row is already exist in one of another table? How should I handle it?

I am Looking for a clean and simple solution or sql example.

Note: I don't have access for creating stored procedures.

Comment: If you cannot create a stored procedure, you need to list your "client software". DotNet, PHP, Java, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're inserting a new `Person` with new `Phone`s, then you would

1. Insert into the `Person` table.
2. Use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html) to get the ID which was just generated on that insert.
3. Use that ID to insert records into the `Phone` table.

If you're inserting a new `Phone`s for an existing `Person`, then you would

1. Select the `Person` to get its ID if you don't already have it
2. Use that ID to insert records into the `Phone` table.

   > What if row is already exist in one of another table? How should I handle it?

Define "already exists" in this context.  What defines uniqueness in your data?  In cases like this you may want to consider incorporating that definition of uniqueness into the primary key in that table.  (Which can be composed of more than one column.)  Otherwise you'll have to `SELECT` from the table to see if the row already exists.  If it does, update it.  If it doesn't, insert it.  (Or however you want to handle already-existing data logically in your domain.)

Keep in mind that it's easy to go overboard with uniqueness in cases like this.  For example, you might be tempted to try to create a many-to-many relationship between these tables so that you can avoid having duplicate phone numbers.  In real world scenarios this ends up being a bad idea because it's possible that:

1. Two people share the same phone number.
2. One of those two people changes his/her number, but the other one doesn't.

In an overly-normalized scenario, the above events would result in one of the following:

1. Both users' phone numbers are updated when only one of them actually updates it, resulting in incorrect data for the other user.
2. You have to write overly-complicated code to check for this scenario and create a new record (disassociating the previous many-to-many relationship), resulting in a lot of unnecessary code and points of failure.